# Remove one value from a matrix and shift value left

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
A= [5 3 2 1 5 6;
    3 2 5 1 5 3]
```

and i have to remove the number 1 from the second line, and shift (the number 5 and 3) to the left. The result must be:

```
A= [5 3 2 1 5 6;
    3 2 5 5 3 X]
```

I put X, because no matter what happens with this number. The size of A can't modify.

Comment: Have you given it a try? Must this be a once off solution? A general solution? If general then you need to provide a bit more info

Comment: the number that's is being removing could be any of all numbers in the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that lets you specify the position of elements in a vector to remove and also pads with `NaN` at the end to keep the length the same

```
function newVec = removeElements(oldVec, elementsToRemove)
    %//You should add some error checking here regarding the sizes of the matrices and making sure you're not out of bounds etc
    newVec = [oldVec NaN(length(elementsToRemove))];
    newVec(elementsToRemove) = [];
end
```

Use like this

```
A= [5 3 2 1 5 6;
    3 2 5 1 5 3];

A(2, :) = removeElements(A(2,:), 4);
```

Comment: there is not a possible way on not using functions, because i am using a lot already of  others programs, and that i pretend to work and contr only in one .m file

Comment: I prentend to work and control only in one .m file, this part of the program.

Comment: @Dan I think he means he **intends** to have everything working in one file